# How can I get the UI component name so I can set and get the values from and to DB?

Tags: java, swing

I am trying to develop a Java Swing UI. We have a simple employee details application where we take input from the user and store it in a database.

This my table structure:

[DB Table Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JFGs8.png)

I am able to store the data successfully in db table. We are restricting the user to only a few fields (again it is based on admin choice), where admin will maintain some configuration in somewhere (like in filesystem).

[Allowed Field](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RHEIC.png)

Currently, we are allowing two fields the user can update. So, when this form is opened, it will populate previous value from db. Once we press the save button it should get persist in db by catching ActionListener event of Jbutton. With below program I can generate component.

```java
public class TextFieldDemo extends JFrame {

    static JFrame jframe;
    static JButton jButton;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        jframe = new JFrame("JText Field Demo");
        String allowedUpdateField = "Name, Adress"; // reading from DB/FS
        JPanel jPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 1));

        List<String> attributeList = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(allowedUpdateField.split(",")));
        for (String attributeName : attributeList) {
            jPanel.add(new JLabel(attributeName));
            jPanel.add(new TextField(attributeName)); // need generate this component programmatically 
        }
        jButton = new JButton("Save");
        jPanel.add(jButton);
        jframe.add(jPanel);
        jframe.setSize(300, 300);
        jframe.show(true);
    }

}
```

and the output it generate (ignore the layout which I need to work):
[Swing UI Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t2Ti1.png)

How can I get the component name so I can set and get the values from and to DB?

Comment: Components don't have "names", but really what you need to do first and foremost is to fix this broken code by getting all that code out of the main method. It has no business there and its placement there is harming you and your ability to move forward. Instead, GUI code should be OOP-complaint code, just like non-GUI code, with instance methods and fields, and by doing this, you can gain references to your GUI components and solve your problem. The static main method should be used only to create your main objects and set them in motion, that's it.

Comment: Also, don't create your key components inline, like you're doing here: `jPanel.add(new TextField(attributeName));`. Instead, if you need access to that text field (which should be a JTextField, by the way), make it an instance field.

Comment: `// need generate this component programmatically` If this is what you are asking (I honestly can't tell, the question is a little all over the place), then we'd need to see the DB data and how you read it.  I think you're going to need a lot more code than you have, but let's get the basic question correct first.  Can you show us how the data is read from the database so we can see how perhaps you might generate that field?

Comment: Oracle has a helpful tutorial, [Creating a GUI With Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/index.html).  Skip the Learning Swing with the NetBeans IDE section.

Comment: Poor title. Rewrite to summarize your specific technical issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to do first and foremost is to fix this broken code by getting all that code out of the main method. It has no business there and its placement there is harming you and your ability to move forward by

1. Limiting an object's visibility by declaring its variable in a restricted scope as per Java's scoping rules, and
2. By restricting your important code to the static world where you lose all advantages of OOPs that Java has to offer.

Instead, GUI code should be OOP-complaint code, just like non-GUI code, with instance methods and fields, and by doing this, you can gain references to your GUI components and solve your problem. The static main method should be used only to create your main objects and set them in motion, that's it.

Also, don't create your key components inline, like you're doing here: `jPanel.add(new TextField(attributeName));`. Instead, if you need access to that text field (which should be a JTextField, by the way), make it an instance field.

So, you look to be tying a collection of String attributes to JTextFields. One way to do this is to use a JTable. Another is to create a HashMap that uses the attribute name String as a key and a JTextField as a value. This way the text field's text can be obtained and also set via the the attribute key value:

```
// here ATTRIBUTES is a constant String array, but it represents a list of attributes
// that can be obtained however you want
public static final String[] ATTRIBUTES = {"Name", "Age", "Address"};

private Map<String, JTextField> attributeMap = new HashMap<>();
```

For example:

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import javax.swing.*;

public class GuiFoo01 extends JPanel {
    // here ATTRIBUTES is a constant String array, but it represents a list of attributes
    // that can be obtained however you want
    public static final String[] ATTRIBUTES = {"Name", "Age", "Address"};

    private JButton button = new JButton("Save");

    // this is a map that ties attribute Strings to text fields
    private Map<String, JTextField> attributeMap = new HashMap<>();

    public GuiFoo01() {
        JPanel attributePanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 2));
        for (String attribute : ATTRIBUTES) {
            JTextField textField = new JTextField(10);
            attributePanel.add(new JLabel(attribute));
            attributePanel.add(textField);
            attributeMap.put(attribute, textField);
        }

        JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel();
        buttonPanel.add(button);        

        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        add(attributePanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);

        button.addActionListener(e -> {
            // do something
        });
    }

    public void setAttribute(String attribute, String value) {
        JTextField textField = attributeMap.get(attribute);
        if (textField != null) {
            textField.setText(value);
        }
    }

    public String getAttribute(String attribute) {
        JTextField textField = attributeMap.get(attribute);
        if (textField != null) {
            return textField.getText();
        }
        return null;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
            JFrame frame = new JFrame("GUI");
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.add(new GuiFoo01());
            frame.pack();
            frame.setVisible(true);
        });
    }
}
```